# My JSON object is returned as undefined despite showing correctly in the chrome console?

Tags: javascript, html, json, getjson, stringify

I'm fetching a random article from wikipedia and I can see the object in the Chrome console as output, but on the webpage, it simply says undefined.
I've tried stringify as well as displaying elements from the object as [2][0][0][3] but none of them work. They all say print 'undefined' as the output rather than the title or content or url of the random wiki page contained in the object.

Script Code:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#random").on("click", function() {
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&grnlimit=1&callback=?';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
          console.log(data);
          $('#result').html();
          $('#result').prepend("<div><div class='result-head'>" + JSON.stringify(data[2]) + "</div></div>");

          //stringify(data[2][0][0])
        }
      })
      .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
      })
      .fail(function() {
        console.log("fail");
      })
      .always(function() {
        console.log("always success");
      })
      //
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="random">Random</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: try that $('#result').prepend("<div><div class='result-head'>"+JSON.stringify(data)+"</div></div>");

Comment: also data is not array

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` — You are making a GET request. There is no content to describe the type of.

Comment: `async: false` — Synchronous requests are deprecated. Don't do that.

Comment: I can't see a property named `2` anywhere in the data that URL gives back. What are you expecting to get?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the content body from the Ajax response you can try something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#random").on("click",function() {
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&grnlimit=1&callback=?';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
        var pageId = Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0] || false;
        if (pageId){
          var articleContent =  data.query.pages[pageId].revisions[0]['*'];
          $('#result').html();
          $('#result').prepend("<div><div class='result-head'>"+articleContent+"</div></div>");
        }
       }}
    )
    .done(function() {
      console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("fail");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("always success");
    })
    //
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="random">Get Random</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the one that worked. The levels is confusing is all:

```
$(function() {
  $("#random").on("click",function() {
    var url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&grnlimit=1&callback=?';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
      console.log(data);
        $('#result').html();
        var pageTitle = JSON.stringify(data.query.pages[Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0]].title);
        var pageContent = data.query.pages[Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0]].revisions;
        var pageCon = pageContent[Object.keys(pageContent)[0]];
        var pageC = pageCon["*"];

        //data.query.pages[Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0]];

        $('#result').prepend("<div><div class='result-head'>"+pageC+"</div></div>");

        $('#result').prepend("<div><h2>"+pageTitle+"</h2></div>"); 


        //stringify(data[2][0][0])
        }}
    )
    .done(function() {
      console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("fail");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("always success");
    })
    //
  })
})
```

Comment: Yeah but I gave you the example that you used in your final answer.... I said it was only demonstrating how to fetch body data...